# tempreture light flashing on audi a4(B5) 2000 model 2.4i

Tags: audi

Hope somebody can help. Tempreture light is flashing after 30 seconds after starting the car, and it stays on flashing. Level is always good and did replace the tank and cap. Also no trapped air in system.Car is idling a bit low 500rpm when cold or on tempreture...although timing was checked by computer.Could there be another switch or relay thats faulty. Thank You, Andre.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Is there any way you might be able to put a live data reader on the car to see what the temperature says? It may be that the temperature sending unit is bad, which never *shows* the ECU your engine is warming up. The temp light might then be flashing to show you there's an issue because it thinks the car is never warming up. The car wouldn't be overheating in 30 seconds of running. I've ran vehicles without coolant (for testing while working on them) for longer than 30 seconds and they've not over heated. While you're in there, check for OBDII codes as well.